# automatically tag mp3 collection using shazam-like acoustic fingerprint

Tags: mp3, music, database, tags, fingerprint

is there any software freely available to clean up the tags in your music collection , based on some sort of audio fingerprint type technology (like how 'shazam' app works on the iphone) combined with a freedb-like database?  my music collection is a 900 GB mess and clementine does not index files as well as i would like it too, because many songs are missing tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard):

> Picard supports the majority of audio file formats, is capable of using **audio fingerprints** (PUIDs), performing CD lookups and disc ID submissions

It's probably the number-one application for such purposes.

Comment: MusicBrainz Picard kicks ass!

Comment: It doesn't work very well for me :(

Comment: Picard uses whole albums, though. I wish I could do this for single tracks